# Require is not defined nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, smartsheet-api

Trying to use this smartsheet api: http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?javascript#node.js-sample-code

and its telling me to do this for nodejs:

```
var client = require('smartsheet');
var smartsheet = client.createClient({accessToken:'ACCESSTOKEN'});
```

So i do this in my main.js file but I get the error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

I think its because im new to nodejs/npm but I cannot find it anywhere where to actually put this require function.  I think i need to mess with my node.js file but im note entirely sure.  Any link to documentation or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: How did u get your node application launched?

Comment: you know, i think that may be my first problem. i dont have a server.js thing going at all: https://github.com/TheBushyBrow/smartsheet_test

Comment: Did you launch the file with `node main.js` through your terminal/cmd?

Comment: i did run `node main.js` and I get
`{ id: 18949130974918340,
  email: 'email@gmail.com',
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'lastnme',
  locale: 'en_US',
  timeZone: 'US/Pacific',
  account: 
   { name: 'email@gmail.com (Developer)',
     id: 45884085350d45924 },
  admin: true,
  licensedSheetCreator: true,
  groupAdmin: true,
  resourceViewer: true,
  alternateEmails: [] }`

Comment: So there aren't any errors when you do that... Right?

Comment: Not in the terminal. But in the browser, the console has that `require is not defined`

Comment: node.js is server side. It doesn't work on your browser

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda the question. How do I get the require to work like in the example? Where do I place the require?

Comment: 1) you can't open your main.js file in browser.

2) the only thing you can do is to write a client side app that sends a request to this file, and retrieve its data.

3) 'require' doesn't run on client side js

Comment: Have you definitely installed the modules using `npm install`? What is the behavior you're expecting to see?

Comment: Dandy yeah i definitely did.  its in the repo.  @Roysh i see.. looks like itll take a bit more time to setup the node page :/ thank you

Comment: What you need to do:
1) Set up an Express server
2) Define in the serve the path/URL that you need to call from client side.
3) Write a frontend app and make a request to the path you've defined.

Take a look at this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_express_framework.htm

Comment: @Royshsuper helpful thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using node-specific calls in the browser! NodeJS is a server-side technology and not a browser technology. Thus, node-specific calls will only work in the server.

The [smartsheet](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?javascript#node.js-sample-code) api you're trying to use needs to be called from the server-side code and not client side code.

For your case, you can set up [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/) and create an dummy api which internally calls the smartsheet api.

If you indeed want to use such calls on the client side, you can use [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/CommonJS) client side-implementations

Answer (score 26):

Try Removing "type": "module", from package.json

Comment: Note: Doing this precludes using ES6 style modules

Comment: But now I can't load other modules? now I get a "Cannot use import statement outside a module" error

Answer (score 9):

Replace all require statements to import statements. Example:

```
//BEFORE:
var client = require('smartsheet');
//AFTER:
import client from 'smartsheet';
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
require() does not exist in the browser/client-side JavaScript
```

More info on [Client on Node.js: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `require` directly in browser. you need [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), a JavaScript module loader.

This is introductory note from [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

> RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader. It is optimized for in-browser use, but it can be used in other JavaScript environments, like Rhino and Node. Using a modular script loader like RequireJS will improve the speed and quality of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is inbuilt in the browser and the best thing to do is disable the es-lint in the project and all these errors will not occur.
Or try out commenting the whole es-lint file.

It worked for me!